# Scala: is Either the only Option?

Tags: scala, error-handling, either, scala-option

In regard to potential runtime failures, like database queries, it seems that one must use some form of `Either[String, Option[T]]` in order to accurately capture the following outcomes:

1. Some (record(s) found)
2. None (no record(s) found)
3. SQL Exception

Option simply does not have enough options.

I guess I need to dive into scalaz, but for now it's straight Either, unless I'm missing something in the above.

Have boxed myself into a corner with my DAO implementation, only employing Either for write operations, but am now seeing that some Either writes depend on Option reads (e.g. checking if email exists on new user signup), which is a majorly bad gamble to make.

Before I go all-in on Either, does anyone have alternate solutions for how to handle the runtime trifecta of success/fail/exception?

Comment: Since records is a possibility `Either[String, List[T]]` would be a better fit, wouldn't it?

Comment: depends, I need to handle Option[T] and List[T] or Option[List[T]]. Right now I do Either[String, SuccessType] for write operations, will do the same for read operations unless I hear otherwise

Comment: @virtualeyes no, you really don't need to handle all those. You said that there are either Some records, No records, or Exception, correct? Well Some records can be a non-empty list of records, No records can be an empty list of records, and Exception is as usual the left part of the either.

Comment: @DanBurton yes, that's what I meant by x,y,z the Either or Option handler casts the query result to expected type; i.e. if I say option[List[Foo]](query), or option[Foo](query) I'll get back an Option containing Some or None result(s) accordingly. Switching to Either-only query results will entail more work of course (have to fold/map or .isRight/.right, or for{ x <- Right projection } through the result), but what can you do, safe is safe, there does not appear to be any other option when dealing with potential runtime failure, Either, or Box or Validation it must be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Option[T]` for the cases `records found` and `no records found` and throw an exception in the case of SQLException.

Just wrap the exception inside your own exception type, like `PersistenceException` so that you don't have a leaky abstraction.

We do it like this because we can't and don't want to recover from unexpected database exceptions. The exception gets caught on the top level and our web service returns a `500 Internal server error` in such case.

In cases where we want to recover we use `Validation` from scalaz, which is much like Lift's `Box`.

Comment: +1, was thinking about letting the Exception bubble up and have web server generate a 500...but Box, Validation, or Either[Fail, Option[T]] provide more control over what actually went wrong, not to mention transactional queries via for{...} block, something you cannot do with Option result types.

Comment: @virtualeyes probably too late but exposing error in the result type is useful when you expect the caller to actually do something with it otherwise it just clutters the chain up to the point that some layer catches it, consumes it (as in remove it from the resulting type) and pass on the rest which is basically what this answer is telling you to do, minus the consuming part because there is not much to do in this particular case

Answer (score 8):

Try `Box` from the fantastic `lift` framework. It provides exactly what you want.

See [this wiki](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Box) (and the links at the top) for details. Fortunately lift project is well modulized, the only dependency to use `Box` is `net.lift-web % lift-common`

Comment: +1 Thanks, what's the difference between Box and Either[Fail, Option[T]]? Presumably Box is easier to work with...

Comment: Well with Box you write less :D. And a Box is a Monad so it is convinient to retrieve any of the three possible states or combine with other boxes. To see how Box operates You can start with [the cheatsheet](http://nerd.kelseyinnis.com/blog/2012/05/16/box-cheat-sheet-for-lift/)

Comment: great link, too bad the author has yet to write the article he mentions on Box with for comprehensions. I'm using Either Right projections on for{...} query transaction blocks, which has been an awesome safeguard. Would be nice to do the same with Box...

Comment: One problem with the Box implementation is the implicit conversions to and from Option. You can end up losing your failure information without realising it if it gets converted to an Option for use in some other API and then back to a Box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my revised approach

Preserve Either returning query write operations (useful for transactional blocks where we want to rollback on for comprehension Left outcome).

For Option returning query reads, however, rather than swallowing the exception with None (and logging it), I have created a 500 error screen, letting the exception bubble up.

Why not just work with Either result type by default when working with runtime failures like query Exceptions? Option[T] reads are a bit more convenient to work with vs Either[Why-Fail, Option[T]], which you have to fold/map through to get at T. Leaving Either to write operations simplifies things (all the more so given that's how the application is currently setup, no refactoring required ;-))

The only other change required is for AJAX requests. Rather than displaying the entire 500 error page response in the AJAX status div container, we check for the status type and display 500 error message accordingly.

```
if(data.status == 500) 
  $('#status > div').html("an error occurred, please try again")
```

Could probably do an isAjax check server-side prior to sending the response; in which case I can send back only status + message rather than the error page itself.